# Air dryer deflector plate.

Tags: patentability

I want to patent a simple metal plate that would redirect the air from an exhaust port of an air dryer.  It would deflect the air from the ground to the sides.  It has already been invented.  But mine would be much much simpler.  I would not be able to patent this invention right?

Answer (score 1):

So long as your new iteration does not infringe upon an old patent, or at the very least improves upon an already existing patent with sources cited. I feel that you should be able to patent your project without too much hassle aside from the wait and the initial investment.